# LWUIT 1.4 player not working in blackberry OS 6

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit

I am trying to port a J2ME LWUIT app on blackberry. I am able to play videos through my app on Blackberry OS 5.0 and below. But it does not work on blackberry OS 6.0 It is something related to OS version. I was able to play videos through my app on Bold 9700 with OS 5, but when i upgraded the device to OS 6, the video player blinks for a moment and then it is not seen again. I am able to hear the audio until i press pause.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a RIM bug which unfortunately RIM is unwilling to fix since they just don't care about anything other than QNX. See [here](http://java.net/jira/browse/LWUIT-230), for some details. The only workaround is to use a native RIM UI for this portion of the UI. We intend to add such a UI to LWUIT but it didn't make it to 1.5.

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for your reply. I saw the release notes for LWUIT 1.5 and it says that there is a fix related to blackberry touch and that the LWUIT guys have used the RIM's native UI Fields for video components. Will i be able to solve this issue if i use the LWUIT 1.5?

Comment: Unfortunately the bug still applies, we changed everything to work exactly as RIM specifies but it only works when no layout manager (RIM layout manager) is used. We need to install a RIM layout manager to position the media on the screen. We are working on a workaround for a 1.6 timeline.